# how to use mysql date_add function in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

i just using sequelize for a few months. This ORM is really fast and efficient. But now im facing a problem, i need to use date_add in my query to add hours in my data.

Here is my code

```
obd_data.gps_data_2020.findAll({
        attributes:[
            'car_id',
            [sequelize.fn('max',sequelize.fn('date_add',sequelize.col('collect_datetime'),'INTERVAL 7 HOUR')),'collect_datetime'],
            [sequelize.fn('timestampdiff',sequelize.literal('hour'),sequelize.col('collect_datetime'),sequelize.fn('now')),'off_time']
        ],
        group:['car_id'],
        order:[['car_id','desc']]
})
```

its completely fine with another mysql query function such a timediff, max, sum , etc. But for date_add, i have no clue why this cant be work. And i haven't found same problem in stackoverflow,

Please help master, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the end, i used seqeulize.literal() to use date_add mysql func haha, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to define a virtual field in your model to do that, date_add does not appear to be a sequelize function.... https://sequelize-guides.netlify.com/virtual-columns/.. This is a field that does not get persisted or anything, just created on a select type thing